# Installing Python wrapper for METIS: Cannot locate METIS_DLL shared library

Tags: python, environment-variables, metis

I am planning to use Metis for drawing some networks and graphs using Python. I downloaded Metis from [here](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/download). For installing the Python wrapper, I followed the instructions given [here](http://metis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but when I run the easy_install command like:

```
$ easy_install metis
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Could not locate METIS dll. Please set the METIS_DLL environment variable to its full path.
```

From the second link above, I understand that I have to specify the full path to some 'METIS shared library' file in the METIS_DLL environment variable. But I don't know what the file is called and where it is located or how I should specify the path in an environment variable.

According to my research on Google, I found out that the file might be called 'libmetis.so' but I don't have any file of that name. Could someone give me a clue on this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are working on Linux, right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working on Linux (because of the .so suffix) and that you have downloaded, compiled and installed the source code linked in the page. User libraries are installed in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` and their subdirectories. Note that you might have `lib64` or `lib32` also, so try searching there. Try also in `/opt` and in the `site-packages` Python external modules folder, although it's usually placed inside `/usr/lib`. Entering `locate libmetis.so` at the command line might help.

If you have downloaded that package and not compiled yet, then you simply don't have that file. Read `BUILD.txt` or `BUILD-windows.txt` and follow the instructions.

Please note that this question belongs on Superuser rather than on Stackoverflow.